# Google Docs multi user real-time text editor for Angular on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, azure, signalr

I'm looking at building support for multiple contributors like [Google docs](https://www.google.com.au/docs/about/) into my AngularJS 1.x application with a ASP.NET MVC backend. Is SignalR still the way to go? It is getting old and with Office Online supporting the same multiple user real-time collaboration is there a better framework available that gives me a better start within the Microsoft stack on Azure?

Answer (score 1):

Consider SignalR https://www.asp.net/signalr:

1. 1.x for ASP.NET MVC,
2. 2.x for OWIN,
3. 3.x for .NET Core (if I recall correctly).

SignalR v3 (for .NET Core) is under active development, so I'm not sure it's "getting old" yet... Sure the older versions are "old", but they work well and are mature/stable, so nothing wrong with using one of those as well.